# Drools workbench 6.4.0.Final - Executing multiple rules that has insert(object) in drools is not working

Tags: drools

I have a Guided table rule where 2- 3 rules get fired. And each fired rule creates a new Fact object by insert(object);
So the issue here is it some times creates 1 object and some times 2 objects.
So when ever 1 object is created, then on re trigger it creates 2 objects.
I feel some instability in the drools engine. Any quick suggestions are more appreciated. I am using drools work bench to create Guided rules
Drools version : 6.4.0.Final

Cheers,
Kalyan

Comment: Yes, there are programs that _are_ buggy, and there are programs that _appear_ to be buggy. People report something and then they ask whether it is this or that. The answer depends.

Comment: Ok In simple, How can we make sure the Rule for insertLogical() rows will run for sure. Some times it will 1 row only and some times 2 rows

Comment: Yes, it may be this, or it may be that. It depends on the transactions, the data and the rules.